# Is there a buffer method for synchronization?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am trying to do streaming one video to multiple clients i need a buffer to keep frames how can i write this buffer?
I am studying on Visual Studio . I need help about that

Answer (score 0):

Any image (e.g. frame) is just a number of bytes (and in most formats, this is now they presented in their structure anyway). Basically, all that you need is to find HOW to get that representation out of objects of your framework.

`std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>` is your friend, if you keep your images in compressed format (like JPEG).

`std::vector<std::vector<vec3b>>` is your friend, if you keep your images in uncompressed format (RGB, YUV, HSV, HSL, etc).

Here I suggest that you keep a single image in a single element of a higher-level vector. As you're into image/video processing, I suppose that you already know how to work with vectors =3

Be careful that this method takes whole lot of memory due to keeping full decoded images in memory. If you want to limit the maximum amount of spent memory, use circular buffer pattern (free in terms of speed and memory,effective abstraction on top of std::vector can be written in something like 15 minutes).

P.S. Also, when you ask a question on SO, try to put as much information as you can - piece of code, framework used, attempted (and failed) approaches to solve the problem. It makes it a lot easier to respond correctly.

Comment: no i dont know nothing about vectors and buffers can you give me specific code block for example

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector - std::vector

Circular buffer - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer